# Google places autocomplete does not return administrative level

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using google places autocomplete for getting detailed info about given address. It works well until yesterday. Today, when I type some street, autocomplete returns info about street, its city, country, but not administrative level. It returns administrative level only when i type city (without street). Few weeks ago, it returned administrative level for street, too.

Does anybody know, if Google has changed something?

Thanks for any help.

My code is here:

```
    <script>
    function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                {
                    types: ['geocode', 'establishment']
                }
        );

        var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(input, 'keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) { // do not send form when press enter
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        console.log(place.address_components);

        var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'order-street-number',
            premise: 'order-street-number',
            route: 'order-street',
            neighborhood: 'order-city-district',
            sublocality_level_1: 'order-city',
            locality: 'order-city',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'order-region',
            country: 'order-country',
            postal_code: 'order-zip'
        };

        $('.order-input').val('');

        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i]['long_name'];
                if (!($('#' + componentForm[addressType]).val())) { // if input is empty, then add value (because of priority, e.g. street_number > premise)
                    $('#' + componentForm[addressType]).val(val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my-key&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: Can you also specify a sample text that you type that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: For example Masarykova, Brno, Czech republic

Comment: If I type only Brno, i get "administrative_area_level_1", which is "Jihomoravský kraj" (in Czech). If i type street and city, I don't get administrative_area_level_1, only street, city, zip and country

Comment: I don't have an admin area level 1 even if I type only Brno. Not sure if something changed on the Google side. Typically they follow the address formatting supported by the official postal service of the country in question. Does admin area level 1 is a part of addresses used in Czech Republic by postal service?

Comment: Yes, it is. Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ik3wd88wcel4jo/Sn%C3%ADmek%20obrazovky%202016-11-03%20v%C2%A013.28.18.png?dl=0

Comment: Probably some recent change in Maps Javascript API, because if you execute HTTP request https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Brno&key=YOUR_API_KEY there are now address components in response. You can get place ID from responses, but not detailed info. Do you use experimental or release version of Maps JavaScript API?

Comment: I'm using stable version. Autocomplete does not return place detail, but in my script when I'm calling `autocomplete.getPlace();` it calls Google Places id for detail info (as I can see in my developer console). The HTTP request is then https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails?2scs-CZ&8sChIJEVE_wDqUEkcRsLEUZg-vAAQ&10e3&key=API_KEY&callback=_xdc_._3vqohc&token=17376. It returns admin level

Comment: And here is HTTP request of detail for calling with street (Masarykova, Brno). It returns no admin area: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails?2scs-CZ&8sEjBNYXNhcnlrb3ZhLCBCcm5vLW3Em3N0bywgQnJubywgxIxlc2vDoSByZXB1Ymxpa2E&10e3&key=API_KEY&callback=_xdc_._n6mi7i&token=50917

Comment: At this point, it's worth filing an issue in the public issue tracker.

Comment: Done. Thanks for advices :)